# Having some problems with rendering an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am able to render out a single frame, strangely enough. But as soon as I render an animation, all my frames are black. I have tried disabling Compositing and Sequencer under the post-processing tab, checked my compositing tree, and even restarted blender.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-m-pUPKYu92R23GOAPRSg8GOUw1hFRjV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try setting the Strength of the World to 0 instead of 1.  That seems to be confusing Blender, having a black world with a strength > 0.

Comment: That was not it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work.  Other than the fact that there are no textures in the blend file the animation renders fine for me in 3.1.  What version of Blender are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is "normal" because you are moving your objects later in the camera view as you can see here, so your first frames of your animation are just black.

[image]

so either change the start of your animation rendering at frame 10 (frame start)

[image]

or change the object animation itself by moving your animation like this:

[image]